# MongoDB - Find elements, where field is equal to at least one value at array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have "reverse" problem to classic "find value(s) in array".

I get array of ids and I want to find elements, which has field with value in this array.

Example :

I have this in MyCollection

```
{a: 10}
{a: 7}
{a: 6}
{a: 15}
```

And I want to do query like this

```
MyCollection.find({a: [6,15])
```

Which would return me

```
[
    {a: 6},
    {a: 15}
]
```

Comment: just to clarify: those are different documents? could you post doc structure  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

```
> db.testdata.find({a: {$in: [6, 15]}})
```

With data

```
> db.testdata.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e800e2abc8519548297bc3"), "a" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e800e5abc8519548297bc4"), "a" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e800eaabc8519548297bc5"), "a" : 15 }
```

And test code

```
> db.testdata.find({a: {$in: [6, 15]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e800e5abc8519548297bc4"), "a" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e800eaabc8519548297bc5"), "a" : 15 }
```

Comment: @libik, I add some test data in my answer. Hope I catch you correctly.

Comment: Ah you were right all the time, I actually put wrong data into query. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can `$gte` - greater and `lt` - less than

```
db.collection.find({ "a" : { $gte: 6, $lte: 15} } );
```

Comment: That would return me `{a: 7}`

Comment: because it equals to `>`, not `>=`. Try updated answer

Comment: I know what it is, but obviously this is not what I want. Look to my example to what I have and what I need to return.